# Java/JPA: Named Native Query with Join throws Exception

Tags: java, jpa, join, nativequery

In my `Benutzer-Entity` I have following `OneToMany` Relationship:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="BENUTZER_ID")
private List<Dokument> dokumente = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my `Dokument-Entity` I'd now like to get a specific `Dokument` by searching it by its `hash-value` and its `foreign-key (BenutzerID)` - I'm trying to do this by `NamedNativeQuery`:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
  @NamedNativeQuery(
    name="findDokumentByHashAndBenutzerID",
    query="SELECT d.* FROM Dokument d "
            + "JOIN Benutzer b ON d.Benutzer_id = b.Id_Benutzer WHERE d.Benutzer_id = ? AND d.Hash = ?")
})
```

When I use this Query in my Database (H2) it works, but in Java i get following exception:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "FINDDOKUMENTBYHASHANDBENUTZERID[*] "; erwartet "FROM, {"
>   Syntax error in SQL statement "FINDDOKUMENTBYHASHANDBENUTZERID[*] "; expected "FROM, {"; SQL statement:
>   findDokumentByHashAndBenutzerID [42001-197]
>   Error Code: 42001
>   Call: findDokumentByHashAndBenutzerID
>   Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Dokument sql="findDokumentByHashAndBenutzerID")
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:377)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:516)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
>       at ch.insidebfh.persistence.repository.Repository.findByHash(Repository.java:91)
>       at ch.insidebfh.application.service.ServiceHelper.findByHash(ServiceHelper.java:18)
>       at ch.insidebfh.application.demo.Sandbox$1.lambda$0(Sandbox.java:92)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
>       at ch.insidebfh.application.demo.Sandbox$1.run(Sandbox.java:91)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

Comment: Please add the exception as text, not as image.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I added the exception as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the exception I would guess that you call

```
 entityManager.createQuery("findDokumentByHashAndBenutzerID");
```

instead of

```
 entityManager.createNamedQuery("findDokumentByHashAndBenutzerID");
```

Comment: Thank you, you're my Man! I used `entityManager.createNativeQuery()`instead of `entityManager.createNamedQuery()`!